# 'int' item is not subscriptable

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, int

I am trying to make a little alien move around randomly, and I keep getting a :
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

This is my code:

```
        if direction == 'left':
            Enemy_X_change = -10
        if direction == 'right':
            Enemy_X_change = 10
        if direction == 'up':
            Enemy_Y_change = -10
        if direction == 'left':
            Enemy_Y_change = 10

        EnemyX[i] = Enemy_X_change[i] + EnemyX[i]
        EnemyY[i] = Enemy_Y_change[i] + EnemyY[i]
```

Comment: This indicates that EnemyX and EnemyY are integers and not array/list. Please check them in your complete code.

Comment: Okay; do you have a question? Do you understand what the error message means? Did you look at the line of code it's complaining about, and attempt to figure out what is going wrong? Did you try to explain to yourself what each part of the code is intended to do, and check if that makes sense?

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because `Enemy_X_change` is not of type list for you to access elements. It is of type int. Try removing `i` in the function like so to make it a int type (keep in mind you will have to modify the rest of your code):

```
        if direction == 'left':
            Enemy_X_change = -10
        if direction == 'right':
            Enemy_X_change = 10
        if direction == 'up':
            Enemy_Y_change = -10
        if direction == 'left':
            Enemy_Y_change = 10

        EnemyX[i] = Enemy_X_change + EnemyX[i]
        EnemyY[i] = Enemy_Y_change + EnemyY[i]
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

`EnemyX[i] += Enemy_X_change` and `EnemyY[i] += Enemy_Y_change` should work. You are trying to use an integer type as an array, so it is throwing the error. I think you accidentally typed `Enemy_X_change[i]` instead of `Enemy_X_change`. It may also be the case that it should be `EnemyX` instead of `EnemyX[i]` also.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying `EnemyX[i] = Enemy_X_change[i] + EnemyX[i]` where it is observable from the piece of code shared that `Enemy_X_change` is an immutable object and you are using indexing operation over it which throws not subsciptable error :-

```
>>> Enemy_Y_change = 10
>>> Enemy_Y_change[2]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```